# Como detectar retorno de carro"0X0D", em um programa cliente TCP?

Tags: c#

Olá, amigos tudo bem?
Em primeiro lugar me desculpe se por ventura eu cometer algum erro no fórum, até porque, é minha primeira vez aqui e não sou programador profissional.

Pois bem, baixei este programa na internet e fiz algumas adaptações e incrivelmente funcionou perfeitamente.
Uso um Arduíno programado como servidor, e a mesma envia frases com (0X0D) retorno de carro no fim de cada frase.
O problema é que quando o Arduíno envia mais de uma frase de uma unica vez, é impresso na mesma linha do txtTalk as frases, mas a ideia seria o programa detectar estes retornos de carro e pular para próxima linha imprimindo as frases em linhas separadas.

Segue o código a baixo e muito obrigado pela ajuda.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /*TCPClient variable created here to be thrown around in different threads & funcs*/
    private TcpClient myClient;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
           

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Parse IP & port info and connect to client, the stream has global scope so that other funcs can use
          Note the usage of BGW is just for realtime display of received messages*/
        myClient = new TcpClient(textBox1.Text,int.Parse(textBox2.Text));

        stream = myClient.GetStream();
        txtTalk.AppendText("CONECTADO: " + textBox1.Text + ":" + textBox2.Text + "\r\n");
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        btnConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btnStop.BackColor = Color.White;            
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*Disconnect from client, close stream first then TCP connection
         NOTE: this is the Disconnect button, not to be confused with server stop(below)*/
        txtTalk.AppendText("DESCONECTADO\r\n");
        stream.Close();
        myClient.Close();
        btnConnect.BackColor = Color.White;
        btnStop.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        /*Listen for incoming messages indefinitely until connection is broke*/
        while (myClient.Connected)
        {
            if (!stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                continue;
            }

            Byte[] data = new Byte[256];

            String responseData = String.Empty;

            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, responseData);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTalk.AppendText("" + e.UserState.ToString() + "\r\n");
        btnSilenciar.BackColor = Color.Red;
        player.URL = @"C:\\mp3 file\\myMP3.mp3";
        player.controls.play();

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTalk.AppendText("Background worker stopped\r\n");
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTalk.Clear();
    }            
          
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSilenciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSilenciar.BackColor = Color.White;
        player.controls.stop();
       
    }           
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método Split para dividir a string com várias linhas e imprimir uma de cada vez.

Seria algo como:

```
    foreach (var line in e.UserState.ToString().Split('\n'))
    {
        txtTalk.AppendText("" + line + "\r\n");
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Woody Costa, vou tentar sua dica...

Comment: Desculpe na demora em realizar o teste com seu exemplo Woody Costa, e essa demora se deu por causa do feriado.. Esqueci de agradecer ao Natan Fernandes que me ajudou na formatação da minha pergunta junto ao fórum. Obrigado Natan... Volto para dar o Feed-back do resultado..Até mais...

Comment: Woody Costa funcionou seu código, apenas mudei de \n para \r para funcionar perfeitamente... Mas uma vez muito obrigado... foreach (var line in e.UserState.ToString().Split('\r'))

Comment: Ok, então você pode marcar a resposta como solução.

Comment: Olá Woody, cliquei na opção you accepted this answer... Para reconhecer como solução sua resposta.. Acredito ter feito correto...Obrigado...